# How do I access the REBOL header?

Tags: rebol

Let's say I have a REBOL script in another file (`imported.r`) that looks like this:

```
REBOL [
    author: {Greg}
    title: {Awesome REBOL Code}
]
x: 3
```

How can I import this file into another script and gain access to the contents of the REBOL header? I'm aware of `load/header` but I can't seem to do anything with it.

`imported: context load/header %imported.r`

What do I do now to access the header of `imported.r` as an `object!`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LOAD/HEADER gives you a block of code, as you can see by PROBEing what it returns. It contains the unevaluated source for building a header object followed by the rest of the script.

To MAKE an OBJECT! from that header code, one way is to

```
>> set [header script] do/next load/header %imported.r
>> header/title 
== "Some script title"
```

or, if you only need the header object, just

```
>> header: first do/next load/header %imported.r
>> header/title 
== "Some script title"
```

This gives you object access via HEADER and the scripts code in the SCRIPT block, as DO/NEXT evaluates only the first expression and returns the result of the expression and the position in the code block after that evaluation.

Comment: You can also do -- script: load/header %imported.r header: take script